# Flip 2 complete edges on 7x7

Tags: rubiks-cube

How can this 7x7 cube be fixed? The edges need to be flipped. [image: Rubik's cube with some flipped edges]

Comment: This is no different to an ordinary 3x3x3 now, so solve it using your usual method for the 3x3x3.

Answer (score 1):

Writing oppYellowfor the face opposite yellow.

Rotate red 90 degrees clockwise;

rotate oppYellow 90 degrees clockwise;

rotate red 90 degrees clockwise;

rotate oppYellow 90 degrees anticlockwise

rotate red 180 degrees;

rotate oppYellow 90 degrees clockwise;

rotate red 90 degrees clockwise;

rotate oppYellow 90 degrees anticlockwise.

You'll still need to sort the corners out afterwards.